# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

EOS.IO's [first moderator election](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Phillip Hamnett - EOS42]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [Philip Kirkbride](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/users/4/philip-kirkbride) who is stepping down.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5767711286099968/0).

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took part in the election! If you want to contact me for any reason, you can find my contact details on my user profile page :)

Comment: Congrats @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 ! Well-deserved!

Comment: Thanks @PhilipKirkbride! And congrats @PhillipHamnett-EOS42!

Comment: Congratulations @PhillipHamnett-EOS42